# Damping to reduce error signals

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, current, resistors, generator

So ive been doing some research on how overshoot can be reduced in an AC servo position system. I found out that tacho generators are used connected from the load to the motor that drives this load. However I found out that it may cause velocity lag and error. I found out this can be overcome by replacing the tachogenerator with an RC network error rate damping but im not too sure about its operation, can someone explain it to me?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a servo position control loop then using a tacho-generator can reduce the speed at which the motor approaches the optimum demanded position. This means that there is less overshoot because the mass of the "thing" being moved is less likely to significantly overshoot the demand point because it doesn't have as much momentum/energy.

Because a tacho-generator produces an output voltage that is proportional to speed, that output voltage can be used to reduce the error signal and therefore control the speed of approach thus reducing overshoot.

Using R1, R2 and C in the circuit can do the same thing. If the output from the error detector circuit (not a great choice of words IMHO) is rapidly changing then the capacitor's impedance will be lower and the error signal amplitude will be reduced by the effect of the potential divider. For a steady error value, the capacitor will look like an open circuit and there will be no attenuation to the error signal.

Hence, the RC circuit behaves like a tacho-generator used to stop speed getting excessive.

> *However I found out that it (tacho-generator) may cause velocity lag and error*

Both will cause velocity lag but neither will create an error unless the open-loop response is low in gain and there is [stiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiction) in the system

Comment: Why does the capacitors impedance decrease?

Comment: Because, for a capacitor $$I = C\dfrac{dv}{dt}$$ and this means that the capacitor takes a higher current when the error voltage changes more rapidly. More current means a lower impedance and hence it has the effect of reducing the error voltage or at least preventing it from rising at too high a rate. Basically (black and white terms) it permits slow changes in error voltage but tries to restrict high rates of change.

Comment: What does R1 and R2 contribute to

Comment: R2 and C1 (imagine R1 is shorted) form a lag network (the basic "thing" that does the same as a tacho-generator). R1 curtails how much the lag network can dictate things at high frequencies - that is usually called lead compensation. Together it's called a lead-lag compensator.